# Excel VBA dynamic vlookup (2 workbooks)

Tags: vba, excel

I use two workbooks daily that have changing filenames, and must do vlookup on book 1, extract data from book2, filter for N/A in book 1, copy and paste N/A's into another sheet in book1 and save as active sheet.

Below is my code so far...please help to fix.

```
Sub todeleteaging1()
    Range("T1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "vlookup"
    Range("T2").Select
    Columns("S:S").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("T2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-16], agingtest0413.csv!C1, 1, FALSE)"
    Range("T2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("S2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("T14039").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("T14039").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$14039").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="=#N/A" _
        , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=#N/A"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\Users\RRF - 113\Downloads"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
        "C:\Users\RRF - 113\Downloads\todelete20180413.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Sheets("Invoice Aging Upsert_04_12_2018").Select
    Range("L11898").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$14039").AutoFilter Field:=20
    Sheets("todelete20180413").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is impossible to fix. You hare trying to use vars that are undeclared and unassigned but there is absolutely no indication what or where they should originate from.

Comment: Replaced code with recorded macro...need to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Your Vlookup will never work with a lookup reference like `$A$2:$A`. Also, what's the point of Vlookup if you return the value from the lookup column? The whole exercise may be easier with Power query. Open both files and merge the them on columns T from the one and column A from the other file.

Comment: I edited my question and replaced code with recorded macro...need to make it dynamic